# Logging SQUID HTTP POST string

Tags: squid

Anyone know how to configure SQUID to log HTTP POST requests? I have it configured to show the query string on a GET request, but i'd also like to see all the POST data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a HTTP POST the data isn't part of the URI so squid does not log it. You will have to use something like wireshark or tcpdump to capture all the HTTP traffic on the line and then analyse the data they provide.